# 'Inflate' a layout which the LayoutInflater can't inflate

Tags: android, xml, layout-inflater

I'm searching for a way to 'inflate' an Android XML layout which wasn't known while compiling. I already searched for hours and always found the answer, that this wasn't possible, because the LayoutInflater can't use simple XML files. Ok, but unfortunately, this is what my app needs to do.

My app receives an Android confirm XML layout, which it has to display. No interactive functionality is needed, just graphical display.
My first idea was to deserialize the XML file manualy and build the content programaticaly. I'm sure this will work, but is there a simpler way or even a library, I could use?

**EDIT**
As I was asked to post some code, I think I have to add some information. I haven't written a single line of code for this project so far. I wrote much code to read third party XML layout definitions (which weren't Android) for a prior project and 'convert' them to Android Views on runtime. Of course, I could do this again, but this was a lot repetitive work. So I'm looking for different approaches.

Comment: @EarlGrey first show what u have tried. Please upload some code.

Comment: @james For this particular project I have no code written at all. I wrote code to read third party XML layout definitions (which weren't Android) and 'convert' them to Anroid Views at runtime in a prior project. I could do this again, but I'm looking for different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really not a simple way to do it. You could use Simple XML http://simple.sourceforge.net/, this will ease the pain of parsing and you can use a generic approach like binding some kind of "pattern" of your generated xml files from the server to an element. You can also get some inspiration from this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-andddyntut/.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I used Simple XML in the mentioned project. But there I had to read components whith no representation in Android. Therefore I wrote classes for these components, adding Simple XML annotations. No problem. But adding Simple XML support to Android's own Views seems...time consuming.

Comment: Well if you already have Simple Xml annotated classes, then you can reuse them and don't bother with Android specific XML layouts, just send your appropriate XML files, parse them with Simple Xml and display the information with Android components.

Comment: I basically did the same in one project and it worked rather well.

Comment: Well, both projects are from the same customer. They gave us the new job, because they don't want to use non Android XML anymore ;) Thanks for the answer, I think it'll be wrapper classes and confering with the customer.

Comment: Well at least until Android supports a way of using LayoutInflater for runtime layout parsing. ;-)
I wish you success with your project. :-)